# Probability exponential distribution example

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

I have problem with this example:

They didn't rest for a minute today at the box office, someone had been there all day.
The time required for customer check-in has an exponential distribution. In eight hours
they handled exactly 160 customers. How much time at the cash register would be enough for check-in
half of the customers?

I think, that the answer is 4 hours, because it doesnt matter what distribution has one customer when they are all independent. But it was said to me that it is incorrect. Can someone explain it to me? How should I calculate it then? I know that the variance is +-3 minutes, but that is for all the customers together. Why it is not half the time for half the customers?

Comment: I think the there is something missing . It is continuous distribution , so you cannot ask for the half , it can be asked for an interval such as "at least half of the customers" or "at most half of the customers"

Comment: So how would it be for at least half of the customers?

Comment: I am not sure but have you studied Erlang distribution? We are basically adding 160 exponential distributions together, which is given by Erlang distribution.

Comment: I have not heard about Erlang distribution.